# Solving $\sin^2x + 3\sin x\cos x + 2\cos^2x=0$, for $0\leq x\leq 2\pi$

Tags: trigonometry

> Solve
> $$\sin^2x + 3\sin x\cos x + 2\cos^2x=0$$
> for $0\leq x\leq 2\pi$.

My answers are
$$x=2.03, 5.18 \qquad\text{or}\qquad
x=\frac{3\pi}{4},\frac{7\pi}{4} \qquad\text{or}\qquad
x=\frac{\pi}{2}, \frac{3\pi}{2},$$
but the answer states $x=2.03, 5.18$ or $x=3\pi/4,7\pi/4$ only.

I got $x=\pi/2, 3\pi/2$ from $(\cos x)^2=0$,
where it is a factor in one of my steps:
$$\cos^2x\left(\tan^2x+3\tan x+2\right)=0.$$

Comment: Here's the [MathJax tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Comment: Is it supposed to be equal to zero? I do not see an equation.

Comment: You will need the $$tan(x/2)$$ substitution.

Comment: If you check the equality for either $x=\frac\pi2$ or $x=\frac{3\pi}2$, you would end up with $1=0$.

Comment: Although $x=\pi/2$ and $x=3\pi/2$ make the $\cos^2x$ factor vanish, they make the $\tan^2x+\cdots$ factor undefined, which is a problem. :)  Testing $x=\pi/2$ and $x=3\pi/2$ in the original equation shows that they are not solutions.

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3725521/find-a-in-mathbb-r-such-that-sin2x-sinx-cosx-2-cos2x-a-is/3725825#3725825

Answer (score 3):

Look at this $$x^2+3xy+2y^2=(x+y)(x+2y)$$ can you see??

Comment: A nice idea to solve this equation

Answer (score 0):

Use that $$\sin(x)=2\,{\frac {\tan \left( x/2 \right) }{1+ \left( \tan \left( x/2
 \right)  \right) ^{2}}}
$$ and
$$\cos(x)={\frac {1- \left( \tan \left( x/2 \right)  \right) ^{2}}{1+ \left( 
\tan \left( x/2 \right)  \right) ^{2}}}
 $$

Comment: You can use this also in other situations.